# Rails / Sunspot / Solr: Duplicate indexing on inherited classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, inheritance, solr, sunspot

We are building a Ruby on Rails application which uses Solr as a search engine. The following version numbers could be relevant to the issue described in the next paragraphs:

- Ruby: 1.9.2
- Rails: 3.2.6
- Sunspot: 1.3.0.rc5

### Background

We have a `Feedback` model that is inherited by different subclasses. The class hierarchy looks like the following (single table inheritance):

```
Feedback
  |- Problem
  |- Question
  |- Suggestion
  |- Announcement
```

In the `Feedback` model indexing is enabled by the following code:

```
searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
  string :type
  text :title, :boost => 2
  text :content
  integer :user_id
  time :created_at
  ...
end
```

### Issue

The issue with this is that when creating, for example, a new `Problem` with a title of "problemtitle" Sunspot initializes the automatic indexing for the `Problem` **and** the underlying `Feedback`. When searching for feedbacks with a title of "problemtitle" with

```
search = Feedback.solr_search do
    with(:type, type.capitalize)
    fulltext("problemtitle") {minimum_match 1}
    paginate(page: options[:page], per_page: options[:per_page])
end
```

two results are found. One result is the `Problem` and the other one is the `Feedback`. This indicates that in a class hierarchy a class and its subclasses are indexed; which should be correct as far as I am aware.

The strange thing here is that reindexing the index with the command `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex` and searching for a `Feedback` with title "problemtitle" results in one result which is the `Problem` created above.

We solved this by adding `:unless => proc {|model| model.class == Feedback}` to the searchable definition in the `Feedback` model. This ensures that only subclasses of `Feedback` are indexed automatically.

### Question

My question is if this is a desired behavior or not (is it a feature or a bug). I do not understand why the reindexing treats the models to index differently than the automatic indexing at creation time. Can this be a problem of how we implemented the class hierarchy?

If more information is needed to answer my question I will try to give it.

With best regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved the mentioned issue by extending the searchable-block with an unless-statement:

```
searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true, 
  :unless => proc {|model| model.class == Feedback} do
    string :type
    text :title, :boost => 2
    text :content
    integer :user_id
    time :created_at
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Sebastian, I believe the problem here is that Sunspot creates a Solr primary id using the full class name and the id:

```
def index_id_for(class_name, id) #:nodoc:
  "#{class_name} #{id}"
end
```

So if your class is indexed as a `Feedback` and then again as a `Feedback::Problem` Solr will have two entries for it and thus return both of them upon searching. Sunspot will then try to match each one against the database, pulling up the same item twice. When reindexing the entire database is dropped and every item gets indexed with its current class - which is why there is only one after you reindex.

We had a similar problem, and the solution was to create an `InstanceAdapter` of our own for STI classes and register it in an initializer:

```
class StiInstanceAdapter < Sunspot::Adapters::InstanceAdapter

  def id
    @instance.id
  end

  def index_id
    return Sunspot::Adapters::InstanceAdapter.index_id_for(@instance.class.base_class.name, id)
  end

end

Sunspot::Adapters::InstanceAdapter.register(StiInstanceAdapter, Feedback)
```

I know this is a little late but hopefully it helps.

Comment: What initializer do you call this in? The Feedback class, Problem class or somewhere else?

Comment: This didn't help us - only using accepted answer solved our similar issue to the OP's one